# ggplot is not displaying the chosen axis scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My issue is that the boxplot output of this code continues to set its default scale rather than following the one I am setting here in the scale_y_continuous...

```
metal_df_1_common <- structure(list(`Plastic Type` = c("PE", "PE", "PE", 
"PE", "PE", 
"PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PVC", "PVC", "PVC", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PET"), `Metal Type` = c("Pb", 
"Cr", 
"Cr", "Cr", "Cr", "Cr", "Cr", "Cr", "Cr", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Cd", 
"Cd", "Cd", "Cd", "Cu", "Cu", "Cu", "Cu"),
`Adsorption Capacity (mg/g)` = c(0.536, 
0.0448, 0.06903, 0.11789, 0.07073, 0.09577, 0.16454, 
0.23847, 
0.08567, 4.93, 4.15, 4.74, 0.527, 3.566, 0.68, 0.546, 
0.9106, 
1.1853, 1.3061, 1.6641)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), 
class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

m_a_ = ggplot(metal_df_1_common %>% filter(`Metal Type` == "Cd"),     aes(x=`Plastic Type`, y=`Adsorption Capacity (mg/g)`, fill = `Plastic Type`)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.8) +  
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, alpha = 1, size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,5,1)) + 
theme_bw() +
theme(legend.position="none",
  strip.background = element_rect(color= FALSE),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0, size=12),
        axis.title = element_text(size=10),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
  ggtitle("Cd")
```

I've reloaded R and downloaded the newer version, didn't change anything. It continues to display whatever default scale R chooses rather than my scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,5,1))  . I'm unsure of why it continues to ignore my set scale?

Comment: It is really hard to help without a reproducible example. Can you include some example data in your question, e.g. using `dput`? I don't see obvious errors in your code. Are you printing `m_a_` after updating the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, ipav! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: When I am running your code, the scale looks as expected. There is a break at 1, 2 and 3. Is the problem that you want to also see the breaks at 0, 4, and 5? This can be done using `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, 1), limits = c(0, 5))`.